# Windows Server 2019 Core (Command Line Only) | Cannot set service to 'disabled' as local administrator

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019

I am trying to disable the native Windows Defender AV on a Server 2019 Core (command line only) virtual machine.  It seems like my local administrator account does not have full permissions to do so:

```
PS C:\> Set-Service -Name WinDefend -StartupType Disabled
Set-Service : Service 'Windows Defender Antivirus Service (WinDefend)' cannot be configured due to the following error: Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
```

I've tried running `start-service powershell -verb runas` to make sure that my command line is running powershell as administrator, but hit the same error.  Can anyone please help me elevate my command line session appropriately, so that I can use the set-service cmdlet?

Comment: The [MS way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/microsoft-defender-antivirus-on-windows-server?view=o365-worldwide#passive-mode-and-windows-server) is to remove the Defender feature or use passive mode.

Comment: Believe what you're after is :`Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true`